# Typescript types conflict

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm getting a strange error to which I can't find the cause.

I have 2 npm packages using typescript:

- ione/common
- react-auth (requires common)

When building react-auth (`tsc -p tsconfig.json`), I'm getting:

```
[I] ➜ yarn build
yarn run v1.6.0
$ tsc -p tsconfig.json
node_modules/@ione/common/dist/components/router/IoneLink.d.ts:5:144 - error TS2344: Type '"media" | "hidden" | "dir" | "slot" | "style" | "title" | "color" | "children" | "replace" | "dow...' does not satisfy the constraint '"media" | "hidden" | "dir" | "slot" | "style" | "title" | "color" | "children" | "location" | "re...'.
  Type '"css"' is not assignable to type '"media" | "hidden" | "dir" | "slot" | "style" | "title" | "color" | "children" | "location" | "re...'.
```

Yet, `react-auth` is not using `IoneLink` component which is inside `ione/common` package.

I checked the dependency versions of both packages, and their `@types` requirements, they're both the same.

The props interface for this `IoneLink` component is this:

```
import { Link, LinkProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from 'react-router';
declare type Props < P > =
  LinkProps &
  RouteComponentProps<P> &
  React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>;
```

Which is indeed large, but does not contain a `css` attribute.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you ignoring node_modules in your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: They both have "node_modules", in the "exclude" section of the `tsconfig.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to pinpoint the issue to the emotion npm package.

After adding `emotion` in the `types` key of the `tsconfig` file, it built correctly without errors.